# Speech recognition on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am doing speech recognition on Raspberry Pi, but the function `recognize_google` does not work on Raspberry Pi. It says recognizers don't have attribute recognize Google. but it works fine on my local system.

Here is the code.

I want to fix this. Is there any configuration I am missing on the Raspberry Pi?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rec = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("F:\\Python\\ai3\\sample.wav") as source:
    recorded_audio = rec.listen(source)
    print("Done recording")
    # with open(f"F:\\Python\\ai3\\{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}.mp3", "wb") as audi:
    #     audi.write(recorded_audio.frame_data)
    word = rec.recognize_google(recorded_audio, language="en-US")
```

Comment: what's the version of `speech_recognition` on your pi and your local machine? `print(sr.__version__)`

Comment: its 3.10.1 in both.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to `pip install google-api-python-client` on the Raspberry Pi.

---

Explanation:

Python-modules may have "optional dependencies" - that is, libraries that do not strictly need to be installed for the module to work, but are necessary for some extra-features. The google-api-client is such an optional dependency for SpeechRecognition. The [pypi-page of SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) states:

> Google API Client Library for Python (required only if you need to use the Google Cloud Speech API, recognizer_instance.recognize_google_cloud)

So, while optional dependencies are a great way to build packages that work with other packages without forcing a user to install all of them, they also create the situation you are seeing where a package has a different featureset even though the version is the same.

Detailed installation-instructions can be found at the [google-api-python-client github-repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)

Other optional dependencies of SpeechRecognition are:
PyAudio (for microphone) 
FLAC encoder (if you are not on x86-based Windows/Linux/OS X) 
PocketSphinx 
Vosk 
Whisper + OpenAI

Comment: it is still throwing this error.word = rec.recognize_google(recorded_audio,language="en-US")
AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'

Comment: ... shouldn't it be 'recognize_google_cloud'?

Comment: recognize_google function works well on my local machine as it doesnt need user pass. but in raspberry pi the same function recognize_google throwing attribute error.